# Aligning contents with responsiveness using Tailwindcss

Tags: html, css, reactjs, user-interface, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make few alignments of Image and Text like below template responsively and in mobile version the main image is hidden and only the rest content appears in same manner.

[image]

I'm trying this in Tailwind CSS Playground. Please find the link [Tailwind CSS Playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Hiw5vXn1JY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Use the following code:

```
<div class="flex">
  <img class="hidden md:block" src="https://static.remove.bg/sample-gallery/graphics/bird-thumbnail.jpg" width="400px" />
  <div class="ml-4 mt-4 flex flex-1 flex-col gap-6">
    <div class="flex flex-1 gap-5">
      <img src="https://www.spartagroup.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Sample-Logo-square.png" width="200px" />
      <div class="flex-1 bg-amber-400 text-2xl">Text Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-1 gap-5">
      <img src="https://www.spartagroup.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Sample-Logo-square.png" width="200px" />
      <div class="flex-1 bg-amber-400 text-2xl">Text Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex flex-1 gap-5">
      <img src="https://www.spartagroup.ca/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Sample-Logo-square.png" width="200px" />
      <div class="flex-1 bg-amber-400 text-2xl">Text Content</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### Output:

In large devices:

[image]

In small devices:
[image]

#### [Tailwind-play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/b78VpWOYwY)